# Cohort analisis for gamers activity

Tags: mysql, datetime, reporting

I want to do some cohort analysis of gamer activity in my games. By cohort I mean some set of users who registered (or had first activity) on some particular date. For example: users registered on 16 June 2014 is one cohort, and I want to calculate retention, average revenue per user etc., based on this particular set of users. The same should be done for 17 June, 18 June etc. Cohorts also could be calculated on monthly basis, e.g. cohort of May, June etc.

To begin with, I decided to do some basic retention analysis, but I am struggling with MySQL as I m not pro in it.

I have MySQL table with gamer activity entries. The simplified structure looks like this:

```
| id | game_id | gamer_id |          day        |
| 1  |    1    |    1     | 2014-01-01 00:00:01 |
| 2  |    2    |    1     | 2014-02-02 00:00:03 |
| 3  |    3    |    1     | 2014-01-03 00:00:02 |
| 4  |    7    |    2     | 2014-01-03 00:00:02 |
| 5  |    7    |    2     | 2014-01-03 00:00:05 |
```

An entry in this table represents some activity in the game. As you can see, there are several games and the same player could play different games. I want to calculate retention profiles for each game.

The result table  should look something like this

[image: retention profiles]

By retention I mean number of users who remain in the game by the end of some particular period: month 1, month 2, month 3 after first activity in month 0. Number of users in month 0 is 100%. If I say that month 1 retention is 33%, I say that 33% of users still remain in the game by the end of month 1 (the following after month 0).

Can you suggest some sources or example queries to start digging?

Comment: Take a look at DATEDIFF(date1, date2), MAX() and MIN().

Comment: Vérace, thank you, looks like DATEDIFF is a good one for my purposes